# ANSI SQL question - how to insert or update a record if it already exists?

Tags: sql

Although I am using mySQL (for now), I dont want any DB specific SQL.

I am trying to insert a record if it doesn't exist, and update a field if it does exist. I want to use ANSI SQL.

The table looks something like this:

```
create table test_table (id int, name varchar(16), weight double) ;

//test data 
insert into test_table (id, name, weight) values(1,'homer', 900);
insert into test_table (id, name, weight) values(2,'marge', 85);
insert into test_table (id, name, weight) values(3,'bart', 25);
insert into test_table (id, name, weight) values(4,'lisa', 15);

If the record exists, I want to update the weight (increase by say 10)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a long time this operation required two separate commands plus some framework to handle it.  Hence the name UPSERT (UPdate or inSERT).  But more recent versions of some flavours of DBMS support more elegant solutions.

The ANSI standard defines [a MERGE syntax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29).  This has been supported in Oracle since version 9i and in MS SQL Server since 2005.   MERGE statements can be somewhat verbose.

```
merge into t23
using t42
on t42.id = t23.id
when matched then
    update
    set     t23.col1 = t42.col1
when not matched then
    insert  (id, col1)
    values  (t42.id, t42.col1)
/
```

I think the MERGE statement was primarily envisaged as a data migration tool, so its syntax demands that we select data from a table, in the USING clause. we can get around this limitation by selecting literals and pseudo-columns from a row-generating device (such as dual in Oracle).

MySQL has a sightly different syntax, [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2009/05/25/mysql-merge-gone-awry/).

Comment: I ended up using the INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: MS SQL Server 2005 doesn't support MERGE syntax. Only SQL Server 2008 and above supports it.

Comment: Looks like sql server 2005 beta had it but not the final release.  2008 got it.  Reference: http://geekswithblogs.net/SabotsShell/archive/2005/08/20/50706.aspx

Answer (score 3):

An approach compliant with older SQL standards and therefore compatible with a broader range of DBMS (as of now SQLite, for example, [does not support MERGE](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg77560.html)) is to use [a technique involving a *mutex* table](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2005/09/25/insert-if-not-exists-queries-in-mysql/):

```
CREATE TABLE mutex (i INT);
INSERT INTO mutex VALUES (0);
```

That enables the emulation of an *INSERT IF NOT EXISTS* statement:

```
INSERT INTO test_table (id, name, weight)
  SELECT 1, 'homer', 900
  FROM mutex LEFT JOIN test_table
  ON id = 1
  WHERE i = 0 AND id IS NULL;
```

In the case of the OP's question that would be *followed* by a simple UPDATE:

```
UPDATE test_table SET weight = weight + 10 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: Actually I'm posting this for my own reference because the source I had (xaprb.com) doesn't come up easily on Google searches. :)

Comment: I like your solution, because it should work on almost any DBMS. But I found a little improvement. You actually don't need the mutex table. Just do a subselect so `FROM mutex LEFT JOIN test_table` becomes `FROM (SELECT 0 AS i) AS mutex LEFT JOIN test_table`

Comment: Unfortunately, this modification did not work on HSQLDB when I tried it.  Worked fine on Postgresql though.

Answer (score 1):

This is defined in SQL3 as [`MERGE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29).

Comment: Great solution, too bad that a lot of databases don't support this yet :(

Comment: SQL Server 2005 supports MERGE, as does Oracle 9i (and higher)

Comment: SQL 2005 does not support merge, it was introduced in SQL 2008

Answer (score 1):

Use an [UPSERT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert) pair of commands:

```
update test_table inner join test_table lookup 
on test_table.id = lookup.id
and lookup.name = 'bart'
set test_table.colA = ....
```

and

```
insert into test_table
select 1,'xxx', 999
from dual where exists <...>
```

Comment: no: you can use the dual table in mySql, too. And in SQL Server you can omit it altogether if all you need is SELECT <values>.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to simply execute an insert and update command, ignoring the error on the first if there's already a record with that key:

```
try:
    insert into test_table (id, name, weight) values(1,'pax',0)
catch (e):
    pass
update test_table set weight = weight * 1.1 where id = 1
```

If you want the initial weight of a created entry to be (for example) 72, use this as the first statement:

```
insert into test_table (id, name, weight) values(1,'pax',72/1.1)
```