# How to check if a record exists using standard sql or sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Basically, I want something like this in standard sql or sqlite:

```
if(record exists)
{
UPDATE record row;
}
else
{
INSERT record;
}
```

I have tried using `"IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM table WHERE value = somevalue) UPDATE else INSERT` but this is not supported by standard sql or sqlite.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662425/4519059) for ANSI SQL and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31429300/4519059) for SQLite can help you ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using REPLACE command. It basically is called an alias for INSERT or REPLACE in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_replace.html).

So now, you just do `REPLACE record`.

Hope this helps! :)