# Need to convert An insert and a delete instruction in database into an update one

Tags: sql, mysql, database, perl

My issue is that we use [Debezium](https://debezium.io/) to monitor the DB events and even when the is a simple update of the data present in the plugin table, the OCS inventory source code performs a delete and an insert operation instead of simply updating the field of the table.

Which means that instead of catching an update event, Debezium catches a creation and a deletion and not always in the correct order which leads us to data inconsistency.

I identified the pieces of code responsible of this defect, but I don't know how to modify them:

There are two *Data.pm* files that have different code for the same instruction.

[Snmp/Data.pm](https://github.com/OCSInventory-NG/OCSInventory-Server/blob/master/Apache/Ocsinventory/Server/Capacities/Snmp/Data.pm)

```
    # Build the "DBI->prepare" sql insert string
    $fields_string = join ',', ('SNMP_ID', @{$sectionsMeta->{$section}->{field_arrayref}});
    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_insert_string} = "INSERT INTO $section($fields_string) VALUES(";
    for(0..@{$sectionsMeta->{$section}->{field_arrayref}}){
      push @bind_num, '?';
    }

    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_insert_string}.= (join ',', @bind_num).')';
    @bind_num = ();
    # Build the "DBI->prepare" sql select string
    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_select_string} = "SELECT ID,$fields_string FROM $section
      WHERE SNMP_ID=? ORDER BY ".$DATA_MAP{$section}->{sortBy};
    # Build the "DBI->prepare" sql deletion string
    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_delete_string} = "DELETE FROM $section WHERE SNMP_ID=? AND ID=?";
    # to avoid many "keys"
    push @$sectionsList, $section;
  }
  }
```

And [Inventory/Data.pm](https://github.com/OCSInventory-NG/OCSInventory-Server/blob/master/Apache/Ocsinventory/Server/Inventory/Data.pm)

```
        # Build the "DBI->prepare" sql insert string
    for (@{$sectionsMeta->{$section}->{field_arrayref}}) {
      s/^(.*)$/\`$1\`/;
    }
    $fields_string = join ',', ('`HARDWARE_ID`', @{$sectionsMeta->{$section}->{field_arrayref}});
    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_insert_string} = "INSERT INTO $section($fields_string) VALUES(";
    for(0..@{$sectionsMeta->{$section}->{field_arrayref}}){
      push @bind_num, '?';
    }

    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_insert_string}.= (join ',', @bind_num).')';
    @bind_num = ();
    # Build the "DBI->prepare" sql select string
    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_select_string} = "SELECT ID,$fields_string FROM $section
      WHERE HARDWARE_ID=? ORDER BY ".$DATA_MAP{$section}->{sortBy};
    # Build the "DBI->prepare" sql deletion string
    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_delete_string} = "DELETE FROM $section WHERE HARDWARE_ID=? AND ID=?";
    # to avoid many "keys"
    push @$sectionsList, $section;
  }

  #Special treatment for hardware section
  $sectionsMeta->{'hardware'} = &_get_hardware_fields;
  push @$sectionsList, 'hardware';
```

I need a modification of those two parts, so that when there is an update, a simple SQL update instruction is performed. Without any delete or insert.

Please note that the Perl code of those two files is part of the associated packages, so modification is not that easy.

EDIT 1 : @RickJames The issue is with OCS. You can see clearly that they make an insert and then a delete instead of simply performing an update when the case is appropriate. That's why debezium is lost. It gets an insert, followed by a delete and this leads us to inconsistency data in our results.We opened a ticket with OCS and they told us that they don't want to improve the code for that purpose but we actually have a real need of an update statement instead of a total re-creation of the line in the table.

EDIT 2 : here are further explications OCS inventory is a solution that centralisez computers on which the OCS agent is installed. There is a Web Server writtten in PHP and another part (the Communication Server) using a lot of PERL code that is used to receive agents informmations and update the MYSQL database. We use debezium to monitor the binlogs of the database. And during agent Inventory the PERL module of the Communication Server performs systematically an insert and a delete aven when the field given by the OCS Inventory AGent could simply be updated. My need is to have an update  case when data can simmply be updated, an insert when the data is totally new and a delete operation when the inventory of the OCS Agent returns the deletion of a line in the table

Can you explain why the INSERT and DELETE might be in the wrong order? If that could be fixed, the problem would go away.
We don't know why it has been developed this way. And when we've asked for an update they told us that they didn't want to modify the existing code and that it had been developed this way for performances purposes

Comment: You appear to be asking how to convert the presented logic into a single "upsert" or [MERGE INTO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2662425/132382) operation in MySQL, which is a [well-trodden path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4205207/132382).  However, _the code you show isn't enough to do that._  The code you don't show, in `Inventory/Update.pm`, suggests that this program might INSERT one record and DELETE _several_ records, which records do not match an XML catalog of some kind.  That's not an easy fit for a one-record "upsert" operation, but we can't be sure with what you've provided.

Comment: Don't worry about the perl, worry about the SQL.  Show us an example of the table structure, the data, and the execution of the separate queries based on that data, and perhaps we can help.  I'd suggest you close this and open a separate question.  Good luck.

Comment: Hello,

What I would like to be precise is that when a field is updated, an update statement is performed instead of a delete and a new insert. Do not hesitate to tell me if you need more information

Comment: Please look at the binlog (use, for example, `mysqlbinlog`) to see whether there are actually `UPDATEs` in the binlog.  I suspect OCS is doing `DELETE` + `INSERT`, thereby debezium has no option but to present those two statements to you.

Comment: @RickJames the binlog is the file monitored by debezium so you're right, the issue comes from the OCS code

Comment: @ArnaudDUBOIS - Moving our discussion to the Question (for fear that the Answer will be deleted).  OK Debezium gets an `UPDATE` from the binlog; then OCS turns that into a `DELETE` plus `INSERT`.  I need some more details -- I assume the binlog is being written in "Row format", which contains the old and new values of the row; do you have any details of the handoff between Debezium and OCS?  (It may be best to get rid of OCS.)

Comment: @RickJames No you are mistaken. Debezium listens to OCS inventory binlog. As OCS code performs insert/delete on OCS Inventory Agent inventory even in the case where only an update is needed debezium receives an insert and a delete which makes the rest of data processing really complicated for us

Comment: @ArnaudDUBOIS - OK I am lost.  Where does MySQL fit in?  Does OCS generate SQL queries and call MySQL?  (I see now that I read your first paragraph as if the steps were in order.)

Comment: @RickJames here are further explications OCS inventory is a solution that centralisez computers on which the OCS agent is installed. There is a Web Server writtten in PHP and another part (the Communication Server) using a lot of PERL code that is used to receive agents informmations and update the MYSQL database. We use debezium to monitor the binlogs of the database. And during agent Inventory the PERL module of the Communication Server performs systematically an insert and a delete aven when the field given by the OCS Inventory AGent could simply be updated. My need is to have an update

Comment: an update case when data can simmply be updated, an insert when the data is totally new and a delete operation when the inventory of the OCS Agent returns the deletion of a line in the table

Comment: Can you explain why the INSERT and DELETE might be in the wrong order?  If that could be fixed, the problem would go away.

Comment: We don't know why it has been developed this way. And when we've asked for an update they told us that they didn't want to modify the existing code and that it had been developed this way for performances purposes

Comment: Please remove the "edit"s. They do [not belong in the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011). The question should be ***as if it was written right now***. There is a full revision history, with edit summaries on why a revision was made, etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution by myself. In order to do what I want to do I need to use this :

```
INSERT INTO table (column_names)  
VALUES (data)  
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

We have seen the two UPSERT commands so far, but they had some limitations. The INSERT IGNORE statement only ignores the duplicate error without making any modification to the table. And the REPLACE method detected the INSERT error, but it will delete the row before adding the new record. Hence, we are still searching for a more refined solution until now.

So, we use a more refined solution as the INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statement. It is a non-destructive method that means it does not remove the duplicate row. Instead, when we specify the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause in a SQL statement and a row would cause duplicate error value in a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY index column, then updation of the existing row occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Show us an example of the `DELETE` and `INSERT`.  Also please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

This *may* suffice:

- Ignore the `DELETE`
- Change the `INSERT` by simply changing `INSERT` to `REPLACE`.

Assuming all the columns are in the `INSERT`, then the `REPLACE` will perform 2 steps:

1. `DELETE` the row(s) based on the `UNIQUE` (or `PRIMARY)` keys in the table.
2. `INSERT`.

Notes:

- Probably there will be no issue with `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns.
- An Upsert (IODKU) would be better than `REPLACE`, but that would be messier to implement.
- If no row exists yet, `REPLACE` acts like `INSERT`.  (This takes care of the case where there is no `DELETE` in the binlog.
- (Flaw) A deliberate `DELETE` will be lost.

Comment: we do not want a systematic INSERT DELETE. We want that when a row can be updated an UPDATE operation is performed. Please Help with the UPSERT Solution

Answer (score -2):

Combining insert, select, and delete operations into a single SQL statement is typically done using the MERGE or UPSERT statement if supported by your database. However, if your current code has separate SQL strings, direct merging might be complex.

Example of MERGE statement:

```
foreach my $section (@$sectionsList) {
    my $fields = join(',', ('SNMP_ID', @{$sectionsMeta->{$section}->{field_arrayref}}));

    $sectionsMeta->{$section}->{sql_merge} = "
        MERGE INTO $section USING dual ON ($section.SNMP_ID = ? AND $section.ID = ?)
        WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET $fields = VALUES($fields)
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ($fields) VALUES (?) WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
    ";
}
```

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT (along with most of this user's other answers)

Comment: Upsert cannot do a Delete.  `MERGE` is not a statement implemented in MySQL.  `UPSERT` is not spelled that way.  Downvoting.

Comment: The [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77537497/revisions) had perfect spelling and grammar (thus likely generated by [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar)). Revision 2 introduced a language error: A [missing article](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Dax90QyXgI&t=17m54s).

Comment: @DavidW: It does look suspicious (e.g., answering rate close to the rate limit), but language errors abound in the other answers: missing articles, grammar, run-on sentences, etc. Perhaps the code is generated by ChatGPT and the text is rewritten ChatGPT output to try to hide it? (This answer being a slip-up, providing some  insight into the ChatGPT workflow by this user.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen - I suggest that providing an answer from chat gpt is OK -- but only if you validate it.  In this case, I quickly found 3 blatant errors.   It will be hard to police against AI.  Especially as AI gets better.

Comment: @RickJames do not hesitate to proive a better answer there is bounty waiting for that :)

Comment: @ArnaudDUBOIS - Please first find out whether the issue is with OCS or with Debezium.

Comment: @RickJames The issue is with OCS. You can see clearly that they make an insert and then a delete instead of simply performing an update. That's why debezium is lost. We opened a ticket with them and they told us that they did not want to improve the code for that purpose but we actually have a real need of an update statement instead of a total re-creation of the line in the table